# Read just the first 5 lines with fileReader

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file, but only want to read the first 5 lines and then print them on the screen. Not sure how to properly iterate this with a loop. The following code just prints the entire file. I also need to check if the file has less than 6 lines in the loo. Any tips greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;

public class File_Reader 
{
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
{
    // int counter=0;String str;
    String fileName = "MyFile.txt";

    String line = null;


      FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);


        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }   

        bufferedReader.close();         

}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just add a counter to your while loop?  It's already executing once per line.

Comment: So changing the `while` for a `for(int i = 1; i <=5; i++)` is really hard...

Comment: Why is the while loop looping until the `BufferedReader` gets to the end if you want it to stop at the 5th line? Just count the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a loop till it iterates 5 times.

```
    import java.io.*;


    public class File_Reader 
    {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        // int counter=0;String str;
        String fileName = "MyFile.txt";

        String line = null;

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

            int i = 0;
            try {
                //print first 5 lines or all if file has less than 5 lines
                while(((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) && i < 5) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    i++;
                }   
            }
            finally {   
                bufferedReader.close();         
            }

        }
    }
```